# transfer and delete file in puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to copy a file from puppet master into the puppet agent. Use it for installation. Then delete back the file. I've tested the script until the installation part and it works fine. The only problem is when deleting the file. After adding a few line, I get this error.

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Duplicate declaration: File[/home/mypackage-4.4.0.rpm] is already declared in file /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:23; cannot redeclare at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:31
```

This is the pp file that i wrote:

```
class mypackage {
    $version = '4.6.0'
    if $::operatingsystem == 'CentOS' {
            exec { "mypackage-uninstall":
                    path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin/','/bin','/sbin'],
                    command => "/bin/rpm -e mypackage",
            }
            file { "mypackage-${version}.rpm":
                    path    =>"/home/mypackage-${version}.rpm",
                    source  => "puppet:///modules/mypackage-${version}.rpm"
            }
            exec { "mypackage-install":
                    path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
                    command => "/bin/rpm -ivh /home/mypackage-${version}.rpm",
                    require => file["/home/mypackage-${version}.rpm"],
            }
#this is the part that i add to delete back what has been copied to the agent
            file { "mypackage-${version}.rpm":
                    path    => /home/mypackage-${version}.rpm",
                    ensure  => absent,
            }
     }
}
```

I have tried changing the declaration to `file {"mypackage-remove":`. But the same error appeard. How can I declare a file used for copy and also declare it for delete?

I'm using CentOS 6.0. My puppet master and agent both are 3.7.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Puppet, you define a **desired state of resource**.

> Puppet is a configuration management solution that allows you to define the state of your IT infrastructure, and then automatically enforces the desired state.

So there is no such thing like file exist for some time, and then it magically disappears. If you used `file` resource to download/copy file, you cannot remove it by `file` resource. To delete it use `exec` eg.

```
exec { "remove file":
        path    => ['/usr/bin','/usr/sbin','/bin','/sbin'],
        command => "rm /home/mypackage-${version}.rpm",
        require => File["/home/mypackage-${version}.rpm"],
}
```

**UPDATE:**
A few things worth mentioning:

1. When you are creating [ordering relationships](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#language:-relationships-and-ordering), you use [resource references](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.1/reference/lang_data_resource_reference.html). So **NOT**:

   ```
   require => file["/home/mypackage-${version}.rpm"]
   ```

   but:

   ```
   require => File["/home/mypackage-${version}.rpm"]
   ```
2. You can use `file` resource as many times as you want to define different files, but each resource must be [unique](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.1/reference/lang_defined_types.html#resource-uniqueness).

   > You can make resources different across instances by making their titles and names/namevars include the value of $title or another parameter.

   For the [file](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file) resource, [path](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-path) attribute is a **namevar**. This means it also has to be unique. Changing only the name of file, without changing path,  will still cause `Duplicate declaration` error.